# Necessary conditions for Lagrange polynomial positive on interval

Tags: polynomial, interpolation

Given a Lagrange polynomial of degree $k$ in second form of the [barycentric interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Barycentric_form)

$p(x) = \frac{\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{w_j}{x - x_j} y_j}{\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{w_j}{x - x_j}}$ with $x_j = \cos(\frac{2j-1}{2k}\pi)$ as [Chebyshev nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_nodes#Definition) and the barycentric weights $w_j = \prod_{i=0, i \neq j}^k\frac{1}{x_j - x_i}$

What are the conditions on $y_j$ so that $p(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$?

Is $y_j \geq 0$ sufficient?

Comment: See these slides http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~jbhu2010/PRESENTATIONS/JBHU2010_Lasserre.pdf.